# `choice == 1` is False even when user enters "1"

Tags: python

I am starting to learn python. I have gone through several tutorials and now I am trying to write my first script. It is a simple console menu. I am running Python 2.6.5 under cygwin.

Here is my script:

```
import sys

print "********************************************************************"
print "**  1) This is menu choice #1                                     **"
print "**                                                                **"
print "**                                                                **"
print "**                                                                **"
print "**                                                                **"
print "**                                                                **"
print "********************************************************************"
print
print "Choice ?"

choice = sys.stdin.readline()

print "You entered: " + choice

if choice == 1:
    choice1 = sys.stdin.readline()
    print "You entered:" + choice1
else:
    quit()

print "Exiting"
```

When I run the script, I get to the Choice? prompt. I enter 1 and I get the "You entered:" message and then the script exits without displaying the "Exiting" message.

Seems like it should be so easy. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: FYI, it would be more common to use `raw_input("Choice? ")` to get user input.

Comment: Can you improve on the question title? It does not describe the question topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing a string to an integer. Try converting the string into an integer:

```
if int(choice.strip()) == 1:
```

Comment: I believe several of the answers would work. This is the first time I've posted a question on SO. This site is great. @Tomalak Geret'kal I will be more descriptive in the future, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `raw_input()` instead of `sys.stdin.readline()`
2. Change `choice == 1` to `choice == '1'`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `readline` returns a string, but your `if` statement expects an `int`. To convert the string to an `int`, you could use `int(choice.strip())` (be prepared for it to raise an exception if what you enter isn't a valid number).

```
In [8]: choice
Out[8]: '1\n'

In [9]: int(choice.strip())
Out[9]: 1
```

Comment: 1+. Hit the nail on the head. Also do note that Python is kind and you can omit `strip()`, int trims for you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but I think the user is entering a string, not a number. The number 1 and the string 1 are two completely different things.

Try choice == "1"

Answer (score 0):

The readline function retains the newline at the end of the input. Your first if should be:

```
if choice == "1\n":
```

assuming you want the newline.

Answer (score 0):

It's exiting by calling `quit()` since it takes the `else` branch. That's because `'1'` (a string) does not equal `1`, an integer.